# to what stage <img/> load event is regarding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

```
$(".img").on("load",function () {...} );
```

does `load` raised when :

- img is fully downloaded to the computer ?

or

- img is fully rendered by browser?

Comment: are you asking about the javascript `onload`  or the jQuery `load` function?

Comment: @gdoron isnt it the same ? i can use `.on("load",` on images.... im not talking about load html ( ajax)

Comment: One way to test would be with a really large image, and have the handler grab the current time when the event fires. It should be possible to watch the computer clock and figure out whether the event happened when rendering started or completed.

Comment: @Pointy. I tried it with 70m image, the problem is I think the browser is rendering the image while download. [isn't so](http://jsfiddle.net/QHdq3/2/)?

Comment: @gdoron yes that may be true ... though it may depend on the characteristics of individual image formats. I don't know much about how that's possible for different formats, but aren't there such things as "progressive" JPEG images? So when you tried it with a big image, did it seem that the event fired when the image started being painted on the screen, or afterwards?

Comment: @Pointy. afterwards. but I'm now sure. Did you try it?

Comment: No but I am going to in just a moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents):

> **load:** The load event occurs when the DOM implementation finishes loading all content within a document, all frames within a FRAMESET,
>   or an OBJECT element.

---

Even more specific [from the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/embedded-content-1.html#update-the-image-data):

> When the user agent is to **update the image data** of an [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/embedded-content-1.html#the-img-element)
>   element, it must run the following steps:
>
> 1. Return the [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/embedded-content-1.html#the-img-element) element to the [unavailable](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/embedded-content-1.html#img-none) state.
> 2. If an instance of the [fetching](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/fetching-resources.html#fetch) algorithm is still running for this element, then abort that algorithm, discarding any pending
>      [tasks](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/webappapis.html#concept-task) generated by that algorithm.
> 3. Forget the [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/embedded-content-1.html#the-img-element) element's current image data, if any.
> 4. If the user agent cannot support images, or its support for images has been disabled, then abort these steps.
> 5. If the element's [`src`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/embedded-content-1.html#attr-img-src) attribute's value is the empty string, then set the element to the [broken](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/embedded-content-1.html#img-error) state, [queue a task](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) to
>      [fire a simple event](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/webappapis.html#fire-a-simple-event) named `error` at the [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/embedded-content-1.html#the-img-element) element,
>      and abort these steps.
> 6. Otherwise, [resolve](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/urls.html#resolve-a-url) the value of the element's [`src`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/embedded-content-1.html#attr-img-src) attribute, relative to the element, and, if that is successful,
>      [fetch](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/fetching-resources.html#fetch) that resource.   The resouce [SIC] obtained in this
>      fashion is the [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/embedded-content-1.html#the-img-element) element's image data.   Fetching the image
>      must [delay the load event](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-end.html#delay-the-load-event) of the element's document until the
>      task that is queued by the networking task source once the resource
>      has been fetched (defined below) has been run.   ...   The task that
>      is queued by the networking task source once the resource has been
>      fetched must act as appropriate given the following alternatives:
>
> #### ↪ If the download was successful
>
> Set the [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/embedded-content-1.html#the-img-element) element to the [completely available](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/embedded-content-1.html#img-all) state, update the presentation of the image
>   appropriately, and [queue a task](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) to [fire a simple event](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/webappapis.html#fire-a-simple-event)
>   named `load` at the [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/embedded-content-1.html#the-img-element) element.
>
> #### ↪ Otherwise
>
> Set the [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/embedded-content-1.html#the-img-element) element to the [broken](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/embedded-content-1.html#img-error) state, and queue a task to fire a simple event named `error` at the [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/embedded-content-1.html#the-img-element) element.

Based on this, specifically:

1. Set the `img` element to the completely available state
2. Update the presentation of the image appropriately, and
3. Queue a task to fire a simple event named `load` at the `img` element

...the load event is fired **only after the image is fully rendered by the browser**.

Comment: Are you thinking of the `<body>` tag's `onload` attribute?

Comment: That is just a hook into the `document`'s `load` event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/body#Attributes

Comment: Well the interesting question I think is whether the event fires when the transmission is complete or when the pixels are all correctly glowing so that you can see what the cat is doing that's so cute.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL convincing enough. great effort.I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

After reading those lines:

> As soon as the image has been loaded, the handler is called.
>
> Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

I understand  answer *"img is fully downloaded to the computer"*

[source](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Comment: However there must be *some* inspection of the image content, because the browser won't fire the event if the "image" is actually not a valid image in a recognized format. (I think.)

Comment: I find this extremely ironic, given that jQuery is supposed to work uniformly across browsers: _"It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser"_

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL. That's because jQuery added features that can't be used no matter how many hacks you use. You can not use those feature. but I find this _extremely reasonable_

Answer (score 0):

You asked: "to what stage  load event is regarding?"

And then posted an incomplete jQuery snippet:

```
$(".img").on("load",function () {...} );
```

An IMG element's `onload` event handler (whose code is handled by the browser itself) is not the same as jQuery's `on` instance method. So it is unclear what you want to know.

As evidenced by your question, the ensuing responses, and the source code itself (read it below), jQuery continues to serve as an example for how not to design an API -- and nearly 7 years after they've been told what's wrong with it.

So what's wrong with it? In a nutshell, jQuery methods are designed with a loose general-purpose contract. They expect anything (string, host object, etc), typecheck, then overload the method with varying behavior, depending on optional arguments, sometimes even optional middle arguments, and use extensive conditional logic to handle all the cases. The `on` method tops it off with an internal flag `one` ( `if (one === 1)` -- what if it's 2?).

```
jQuery.fn.extend({

on: function( types, selector, data, fn, /*INTERNAL*/ one ) {
    var origFn, type;

    // Types can be a map of types/handlers
    if ( typeof types === "object" ) {
        // ( types-Object, selector, data )
        if ( typeof selector !== "string" ) { // && selector != null
            // ( types-Object, data )
            data = data || selector;
            selector = undefined;
        }
        for ( type in types ) {
            this.on( type, selector, data, types[ type ], one );
        }
        return this;
    }

    if ( data == null && fn == null ) {
        // ( types, fn )
        fn = selector;
        data = selector = undefined;
    } else if ( fn == null ) {
        if ( typeof selector === "string" ) {
            // ( types, selector, fn )
            fn = data;
            data = undefined;
        } else {
            // ( types, data, fn )
            fn = data;
            data = selector;
            selector = undefined;
        }
    }
    if ( fn === false ) {
        fn = returnFalse;
    } else if ( !fn ) {
        return this;
    }

    if ( one === 1 ) {
        origFn = fn;
        fn = function( event ) {
            // Can use an empty set, since event contains the info
            jQuery().off( event );
            return origFn.apply( this, arguments );
        };
        // Use same guid so caller can remove using origFn
        fn.guid = origFn.guid || ( origFn.guid = jQuery.guid++ );
    }
    return this.each( function() {
        jQuery.event.add( this, types, fn, data, selector );
    });
},
one: function( types, selector, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, selector, data, fn, 1 );
}
```